# Robot framework promise handling

Tags: javascript, promise, robotframework, selenium2library

Is there a way in Robot Framework to run a javascript method that returns a promise and resolve that promise so I could get a result from it? I tried to achieve it in two ways. The first way was to run the `Execute Javascript` keyword and pass the function, then set wait for some time (with `Sleep`) and trying to resolve the promise (it already finished to execute in the browser).

The code I used looks like that:

```
${promise}= Execute Javascript  return runAllTests();
Sleep   30sec   
${result}=  Set Variable    return ${promise}.then(function(result) { return result; });
```

The result I got with this was just the promise object (I think)

```
{u'all': {}, u'_setSettlePromisesQueued': {}, u'_setBoundTo': {}, u'_settlePromiseAtPostResolution': {}, u'_isRejectionUnhandled': {}...
```

I do not paste it all because it's 3000+ characters long, but it's not what I expected for sure. Actually, the result is exactly the same no matter if I put there `Sleep` keyword or not.

The second way was to use `Execute Async Javascript` keyword (with modified timeout) and then trying to resolve it.

```
Set Selenium Timeout    30sec
${result}=    Execute Async Javascript    return runAllTests().then(function(result) { return result});
```

The function finished to execute in the browser window, but Robot seems not to care and after 30 seconds it reports `TimeoutException` with this message:

> TimeoutException: Message: asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 30 seconds

I tried to find another way, maybe some built-in mechanism to handle the promises, but I did not find anything like that. Is there any way to do that? I use Robot with Selenium2Library.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is basically in the Selenium2Library documentation. All it takes to make it work is to use the *callback* function, for example:

```
Set Selenium Timeout    60sec
${result}=    Execute Async Javascript
...    var callback = arguments[arguments.length-1];
...    runAllTests().then(function() { callback(1); }).catch(function() { callback(0); });
```

This will set the result to 1 or 0 (as a string, not integer), depending on what is returned by this function (resolved or rejected promise). I was confused by this *callback* used in this example but it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Following keyword allows getting back the promise response or error message.

```
PS Execute Async Promise
    [Arguments]    ${promise}    ${timeout}=${PS_MAX_WAIT}    ${return_function}=${None}    ${failure_marker}=UNEXPECTED_STATE
    [Documentation]    Wrapper calling a asynchronous JavaScript ${promise} and wait till max ${timeout}, if it's promise returns \ a success or failure.
    ...
    ...    Failure case:
    ...    - \ the error.message is catched and reported
    ...
    ...    Success case:
    ...    - When ${return_function} is None, the promise response will be returned directly (default)
    ...    - Otherwise, an additional *then* chain step is added to modify / prepare promise response .
    ...
    ...    Sample: If ${return_function} is _JSON.stringify(response)_ , a chain step _then( function(response) { return JSON.stringify(response); } )_ is added
    [Tags]    internal
    Set Selenium Timeout    ${timeout}
    ${promise_chain}=    Set Variable If    '${return_function}'!='${None}'    ${promise}.then( function(response) { return ${return_function}; } )    ${promise}
    ${error_return}=    Set Variable    '${failure_marker} - ' + error.name + ' - ' + error.message
    ${result}=    Execute Async Javascript    var callback = arguments[arguments.length-1];    ${promise_chain}.then(function(response) { callback( response ); }).catch(function(error) { callback( ${error_return} ); });
    Should Not Contain    ${result}    ${failure_marker}    js call aborts with ${result} - ${promise_chain}
    [Teardown]    PS Set Delay and Timeout to Default
    [Return]    ${result}
```

Sample robot suite using this keyword see [robot-framework_sample_promises.robot](https://gist.github.com/lczub/869f065d216f01618c285b68e43ec213).

It interacts with sample page [Promises tests](https://googlesamples.github.io/web-fundamentals/fundamentals/primers/async-example.html), provided by [JavaScript Promises: an Introduction](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises)

Comment: Thanks, but it was a while ago, I don't work with Robot Framework anymore and I won't be able to check this solution in the nearest future :) But thanks anyways :)